# BackGroundColorSpan to HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html

im trying to manipulate one HTML file, in the html, it have a javascript function for passing the text of the

to the ANDROID program, and then open a window, where i can edit it and send the text back to the html and the javascript will handle to replace the text, the poblem is, its not working for backgroundColorSpan, and really need it

the Html.toHtml or fromHtml can handle the `new ForeGroundColorSpan`, Bold and Italic very well, but the foreground, it disapear from the html code and dont return too, is there any way to handle so i can edit and see the background on the Android EditText and send it back?

Comment: you should post some code samples so community can see where the problem is..

Comment: thats the problem, there is no code to work, it work ForegroundColorSpan, but for the BackGroundColorSpan no, thats the problem, i cant even reproduce a code

Comment: AFAIK android spans only work on android, it is not universal, so it will look great on your `Edittex` but outside it, just tin air

Comment: Elitz, do you know any way to work with   thr html(edit and save) can be in javascript, do you know any script that appaer bubble menu when you do a selection? Menu like copy paste edit bold etc...

Comment: have you found any solution? @user2582318

Comment: @Kartheek yes, changed the way, not using textview, now i use a WebView, and handle the text there using Javascript and HTML, no more spannables =(